# How to develop a walk through dialog that appears on the first launch?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-dialog

I would like to develop a Dialog which is composed of 3 steps to guide the user when he launches the app for the first time.

The following image is an example of what I would like to achieve:

[image]

1- I would like to know how to add a mark to close the dialog at the top-right corner?

2- How can I implement the small circles at the bottom of the screen that indicates the current step? Can they be created programmatically?

3-Only to be sure, I decided to navigate between the Dialog steps using a **ViewFlipper**. Is this the right approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know how to add a mark to close the dialog at the
>   upper right corner?

Don't do that. That looks like it was a straight port from an iphone app. Use the native android dialog containers/buttons.

> How can I implement the small dots at the bottom of the screen that
>   indicates the current step?

What have you tried? There's a million ways of doing this depending on the rest of the workflow.

> Only to be sure, I decided to navigate between the dialog steps using
>   a ViewFlipper. Is this the right approach?

Maybe. It depends what you're displaying. If you're only displaying a single image or something simple, then that might be the best approach. I would create different dialog fragments ( you are using fragments, right?) for the different steps. That way you can automatically push them to the back stack as you move through the workflow.

Comment: Instead of declaring there are a million ways of doing that, you could have suggested 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways to implement the "little dots on the bottom" is :

- include the dots in every image you are creating.
- draw one of the dots highlighted in every image
- flip through the images in order of the highlighted dots. (or highlight the dots in the order you want to show your images)

but this would make your dots disappear during the images are flipped.

if you want to avoid that :

- create two different image views , one acts as a container for the main image, the other as a container for the dots, place the 1st image view above the other.
- create a no of images containing just a no of dots, each with one of the dots highlighted
- flip through both the imageViews in synchronization
- use a "flip animation" in the upper image view
- use no animation, or a minimal animation for the dots.

This will produce the desired effect. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there another way to create the dots programmatically. I am afraid that adding them in an imageView will result in a bad user experience on different screen densities.

Comment: I'm not aware of any available default implementation of this animation, if there is any at all. If there isn't, I'm afraid doing it programmatically is not possible.